# Where can I find a log or see the progress of importing images in MAAS?

Tags: maas, logging

It seems like you tell it to import boot images and then just wait blind for a few hours. Where can you find a log of what it is doing, or get the current progress (and if it has errors and quits, see WHY it quits)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs can be found in `/var/log/maas/celery.log` and they should look like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7652758/. More specifically the task called tasks.import_boot_images.

It's not possible to see the current progress. That's been filed as bug [1271188](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1271188)